# git command erased all files, need recovery

Tags: github

AS i am new to github, and i was asking question on swift many a times experts asked me to upload stuff on github, i did that creating an account on github and readings instructions, as i was doing some commits, i felt the need to undo all commits and typed in

```
git rm -r <mydirectory>
```

and BOOM all my work is gone, i have a back up but its almost 10 days back, tons of work is gone, can any one help me recover or it is gone?

UPDATE - i am new here and trying all commands like `reset HEAD`  but all my files are just empty with no code in them, is there any way i can get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If files were not commited, it indeed gone(

if they were commited, you can restore them since last commit, using

```sh
git reset --hard
```

check [git-reset docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

By the way, github != git so it is not connected somehow with github, it is just normal git  behavior, and I really advice you to read docs before using it.

Comment: thanks a lot , i am trying with the command but in my xCode all files are empty and many errors are showing up , every thing is messed up

Comment: will i need to restore mac to back in time